How to prove that $\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(x+t)\frac{\sin(jt)}{t}dt = \varphi(x)$?
The function $\varphi(x)$ is Smooth and compact supported.
I need to prove that:
$$\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(x+t)\frac{\sin(jt)}{t}dt = \varphi(x)$$
My attempt:
Record the function  $\frac{\sin(jt)}{t}$ by $f_j(t)$, and the proposition changes into:
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}\varphi \times f_j(x) = \varphi(x)$$
Using the Fourier Transformation:
$$\varphi \times f_j(x)=2\pi F^{-1}[\hat{\varphi}\cdot\hat{f_j}](x)$$
I calculated that $\hat{f_j}(\lambda)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot I_{[-j,j]}$
($I$ is the Indicative function of interval $[-j,j]$)
And I stop here. I don't know how to deal with the integral or whether this method works.
Any other different methods is welcome!
Thank you in advance!

My book uses this proposition to prove that the limit of $f_j(t)$ is $\delta(t)$ so I'd better avoid circularity.

As a hint, note that $$\operatorname{Si}(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin t}{t},\mathrm{d}t$$ is continuous, bounded, $\operatorname{Si}(\pm t)\to\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ as $t\to\infty$ (see Dirichlet integral), and satisfies $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\operatorname{Si}(jt)=\frac{\sin(jt)}{t}.$$ Now, perform integration by parts to the original integral and invoke the dominated convergence theorem to conclude. Check my previous answer for more details.

It's really helpful. It' impressive to use a variable upper limit integration. Usually I won't change the formula into a form that seems more complicated. Thanks Lee !
